# Org mode refile - multiple locations with same name as target

Tags: org-mode

My `~/.emacs` contains the following:

```
(setq org-refile-targets '((org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 3)))
```

The structure of the org file is:

```
* H1
** Same Name
* H2
** Same Name
```

Now, when I `C-c C-w` to refile, how do I select H1 -> Same Name or H2 -> Same Name as a target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `org-refile-use-outline-path` to `t` You will see the full ancestry of candidate headings when refiling- which should make it easy to distinguish between headings with a common name.  Alternately you can specify `'file`, `'full-file-path`, or `'buffer-name`.

The docstring for `org-refile-use-outline-path`:

> Non-nil means provide refile targets as paths. So a level 3 headline
>   will be available as level1/level2/level3.
>
> When the value is ‘file’, also include the file name (without
>   directory) into the path.  In this case, you can also stop the
>   completion after the file name, to get entries inserted as top level
>   in the file.
>
> When ‘full-file-path’, include the full file path.
>
> When ‘buffer-name’, use the buffer name.